# Printing images inside tables with Python

Tags: python, image, jupyter

Im using anaconda jupyter notebook.

I have a football players dataset, and one of my columns is named "Photo", which has an URL that links to a png of the player.

I can get the picture of one singular player when I use:

```
img = fifa.Photo[2]
from IPython.display import Image
Image(url=img)
```

This results me the png, I can see the picture.

I´ve been trying to create a visual table with Name and Photo as Columns, but I always get in return the URL as string.

I tried to concatenate (fifa.Photo returns the URL):

```
fifa['concat_photo'] = "Image(url=" + fifa.Photo + ")"
```

in a new column, but it did not worked as well, returns the string, not the picture.

Any hints, please?

Comment: `"Image(url=" + fifa.Photo + ")"` is a string. Try assigning the Image itself `= Image(url=fifa.Photo)`.

Comment: You may need to set the [`embed`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image) parameter to True.